# App Inventor 2 special character for adding a "space" character when joining text

Tags: app-inventor

I'm mocking up an android app, using App Inventor 2. I utilize two textboxes where user inputs e.g. username and password. I store those two text inputs in a TinyDB tag, combined using join text.

From a listview, user picks a "nickname" that is stored in a TinyDB tag. What I can't achieve succesfully, is sending user an SMS, by having these TinyDB tags combined in a string seperated with a "space" text character. Something like that: "tag1" space "tag2".

I have already tried to use "replace all text" block with no success, as I'm geting the SMS in one string without any spaces. It would very helpful if somebody could direct me to the right path, to get this app running, or sharing a code snippet or special characters usage in App Inventor 2.

Answer (score 0):

use the **join** block to join the following 3 elements:

- *tag1*
- a text block, which contains a space and
- *tag2*

see also the documentation http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/blocks/text.html#join
see also how the mutators work http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/concepts/mutators

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)